# Why can we get the pressed button in OpenFileDialog without a listener?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

In C# we can do something like:

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
  if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    pbxPhoto.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.OpenFile());
  }
```

But why can we find out what button was pressed without a listener? Does the program flow stop right before the "if" clause till the open file dialog is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ShowDialog()` method of the `OpenFileDialog` class internally handles the button click events, and then returns a `DialogResult` return type indicating which of the buttons was pressed. (So yes, the method is called synchronously, so flow through your calling method does stop until the dialog returns.).

You can mimic this behaviour if you write your own modal dialog class (or user control), in which you handle the button click events internally in the dialog class and then provide an enumeration as a result to encapsulate the internal workings of the dialog.

As an alternative you could add your own handler to the [FileOk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.fileok) event, but this would probably make more sense using non modal `Show()` as per Justin's answer.

Comment: When exactly the `ShowDialog()` method returns?

Comment: @hattenn As soon as the user closes the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is yes.  The ShoweDialog call will block until the modal dialog is closed.  If you want different (i.e. non-modal) behaviour, you need to call Show() instead.

Answer (score 1):

ShowDialog is a modal form which means that it must be dismissed before the application returns to its normal states. When ShowDialog method is called, it returns an enum containing the states after one of the buttons on the Dialog Box is pressed. For example, if the user presses OK, then the DialogResult is set to OK and is returned to the caller. The caller then determines what to do from the returned result (Enum).